# checkboxlist issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have 5 `CheckBoxList` controls with `ID`'s of `CheckBoxList1`,`CheckBoxList2`, and so on. They have same list items within them.

Now when I write the following line:

```
CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

It selects the 1st item of `CheckBoxList1` but the 1st item of all the other `CheckBoxList`'s gets selected as well. Any idea why is such a mysterious thing happening?

All the `CheckBoxList`'s have the same number of items, with each item having the same text and the same value.

They are populated dynamically with data being fetched from the database.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE EMPLOYEE_TABLE.EmployeeID NOT IN (SELECT ORG_UNIT.ManagerID FROM ORG_UNIT WHERE ORG_UNIT.OrgUnitID = '" + teamid + "') AND EMPLOYEE_TABLE.OrgUnitID = '" + teamid + "'",con);

DataSet da = new DataSet();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
adapter.Fill(da);
int count = da.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();
CheckBoxList2.Items.Clear();
CheckBoxList3.Items.Clear();
CheckBoxList4.Items.Clear();
CheckBoxList5.Items.Clear();

no_of_listitem = count;

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(temp);
    CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(temp);
    CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(temp);
    CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(temp);
    CheckBoxList5.Items.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code snipes of how you initiate some of this CheckBoxList's ? 2 of the will be enough

Comment: Please provide the population function ..

Comment: try this CheckBoxList1.Items[2].Selected = true; if the same thing happens let me know

Comment: item[2] of all the checkboxlists gets selected.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because of the way you are populating those lists ...

I guess you are adding the same objects to each list. So any modification on any object effects all lists ..

---

### Use the following statement:

```
    CheckBoxList.Items.Add(New ListItem(table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString(), 
table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString()));
```

Comment: how do i solve the issue? i mean what is that i need to change.?

Comment: i have to add items to the list dynamically. i have provided the code how i am adding the items to the lists.
how can i then use the statement u have provided ???

Comment: you are adding the same object to all lists

Comment: I guess that as a developer you should know that he needs to replace the above statement with the appropriate one for each CheckBoxList ..

Comment: my comment was intended for Anargha

Comment: hey thanks a lot.. that solves the problem. can u explain why was it happening like that?? the items which i were adding to the checkboxlists are the same even now. i dont see any difference between the two..

Comment: @Anargha: You were referencing the same object from different locations .. When you change that object all the references will be affected.

Comment: @Anargha there is a difference between an object and the value of an object. Different objects can have the same value. If 2 objects have the same value that doesn't mean that they are the same obj.

Answer (score 1):

Akram is correct - all the of `CheckBoxList`'s contain not only items that *look* the same, they *are* each one in the same. So, in order to answer your question directly, you'll need to add a `new ListItem` for each `CheckBoxList`, for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var firstName = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString()
    var employeeId = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();

    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = firstName, Value = employeeId });
    CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = firstName, Value = employeeId });
    CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = firstName, Value = employeeId });
    CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = firstName, Value = employeeId });
    CheckBoxList5.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = firstName, Value = employeeId });
}
```

Comment: thank you.i got the issue solved by akram's idea.i understood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(temp);

    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(temp);

    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(temp);

    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(temp);

    ListItem temp = new ListItem();
    temp.Text = table.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString();
    employeeid[i] = table.Rows[i]["EmployeeID"].ToString();
    temp.Value = i.ToString();
    CheckBoxList5.Items.Add(temp);
}
```