# C#: Need to apply a "label" to a specific asp:CheckBoxList item that is visible to the user, but

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I need to apply a "label" to a specific CheckBoxList item that is visible to the user, but still be able to select the item by name without the label being included in that name.

Currently, as a placeholder, I have a CheckBoxList item that has text "A OR B OR C" and I do cbl.findByText("A OR B OR C") to select that item. What I need to be able to do is make A, B, and C separate list items, and tag each with a common, visible label...probably a number. However, I'm not very experienced with either C# or asp forms, and can't figure out what to use to get around at least one of these two problems: I don't know how to apply two separate visible values to a CheckBoxList item(if it's even possible), and if I make them one value("A - 1" for example), I don't know how to search a CheckBoxList with wildcards.

I'm sure this seems like a stupid question to some of you, but without knowing where to start, I ran out of ideas on what to search for on google. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with some help from this question: [checkboxlist issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728943/checkboxlist-issue)

When I create the CheckBoxList item, I just have to do:

```
cbl.Add(new ListItem { Text = (entry + " - " + label), Value = entry});
```

instead of:

```
cbl.Add(entry);
```

and findByValue instead of findByText.